# Windows 7 host; Ubuntu 11.04 VM machine, no copy/paste

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

Basically, as the titles says I've got a Windows 7 host, with VMWare installed.  I'm using VMware 7.1.3 and everything works fine apart from one thing.

Recently (literally today) for no obvious reason the copy and paste clipboard between the host and virtual machine has stopped working.  I reinstalled the vmware tools on the guest and the vmware tools are running as I've done /etc/init.d vmware-tools start.

Can anyone think of any reason why the copy/paste between the two systems would stop working and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try rebooting the host by any chance?

Comment: Yupp, and the guest

Comment: Well then I have nothing... sorry.

Comment: Have you tried running vmware-toolbox &

Comment: Yeah this brings up the toolbox but doesn't appear to do a lot else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created a new virtual machine in the end, really stumped, but it fixed it!